# Excel VBA .Find Function changing values in selection

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

Heya this is probably simple but I cannot figure out what is wrong.

I am trying to do .find for a specific date and change that selection to a user input date.

I have a userform to select a date from a combobox (date1_cbo). The combobox source is linked to dates on a worksheet (Backend). There is a textbox below for writing the new date to change it to (date1_txt). I keep getting an error

> object variable or with block variable not set.

I have tried a few options without any luck here is my code:

```
Dim selection As Range
Dim check As Boolean

'input box validation
check = IsDate(date1_txt.Value)
If check = True Then
    'find cell matching combobox
    With Worksheets("Backend").Range("A1:A500")
        Set selection = .Find(date1_cbo.Value) 'this is the problem
        selection.Value = date1_txt.Value
    End With
Else
End If
```

Interestingly .Find returns the range or Nothing. however because the combobox is linked to the cells I am searching through this should never return nothing... I dont understand why the error is occurring.

Comment: What error?  Where?  ...also, `Find` searches cell, not combo boxes.

Comment: Is there a value in `date1_cbo`? Can you write `MsgBox date1_cbo` before the error and see what does it return?

Comment: ok "that' error: that is `date1_cbo`? Is that supposed to refer to the combo box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a variable named as 'selection' is bad coding practice but totally legal. Don't use such names for the sake of clarity.

---

Error 91 is caused when you are trying to read a property( `.value`) from null object. your selection variable is null cause date formats on the sheet and combobox are different.

---

Just convert to date before attempting to find it in sheet. 
`Set selection = .Find(CDate(date1_cbo.Value))  '/ once again, selection is valid but bad name for variable.`

Comment: Thanks you were right. It was some type of formatting issue with date. That is interesting because I made sure the format for the combobox was the exact same as the format for the range of cells.  Also I changed selection to rng haha thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a variable named `Selection`. VBA uses it as well. Rename your variable to anything else, rewrite your code and it should work. Even `Selection1` is quite ok:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim selection1 As Range
    With Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A500")
        Set selection1 = .Find("vi")
    End With

    If Not selection Is Nothing Then
        selection1.Value = "some other value"
    End If

End Sub
```

---

To change multiple values with `Find()` as here - `A1:A10`, then some possibility is to do it like this:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim myRng As Range

    With Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A500")
        .Range("A1:A10") = "vi"
        Set myRng = .Find("vi")
        If Not myRng Is Nothing Then
            Do Until myRng Is Nothing
                myRng.Value = "New value"
                Set myRng = .Find("vi")
            Loop
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

It is a bit slow, as far as it loops every time and it can be improved, if the range is united and replaced at once.

Comment: Thanks this would work also, however, there is no need for a loop as there are no duplicate values so finding the first instance of the date and changing it would be all I need.

Comment: @JoeyScott - You are welcome. In general, you never know, next time you may need multiple cases.